# Rails/Jquery Ajax - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, but JSON is Valid

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, coffeescript

I'm working on a hotel aggregation site that lets the user adjust filters (e.g. price or number of guests) and watch the availability of accommodations refresh via ajax. It's built on Rails 4 with CoffeeScript and Jquery.

Here is the JQuery call (Coffeescript):

```
$.ajax '/accommodations/show',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType : 'script'
      data:
        privates: include_privates
        shared: include_shared
        homes: include_homes
        price_range: price_range
        start_date: start_date
        end_date: end_date
        num_guests: num_guests
      success: (data) ->
        #RESPONSE DOES NOT HAPPEN HERE, IS HANDLED IN SHOW.JS.ERB
        console.log "Success!"
        console.log data
      error: (data, status, error) ->
        console.log 'How embarassing! Something went wrong - please try your search again. '
        console.log "Status: #{status}"
        console.log "Error: #{error}"
```

90% of the time, this code works. The other 10% of the time, the server returns 200 status (okay), but the Jquery fails and the console displays the following:

```
How embarassing! Something went wrong - please try your search again. 
Status: parsererror
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Every other stackoverflow question with this issue looks like it was invalid JSON being passed back to Jquery. I identified the problem line in **show.js.coffee.erb**. It is where we convert the rails models into JSON so it can be passed to javascript.

```
$('.refresh-loading').hide()
//Adding the accommodation modules to the left-hand side
$('#accommodation-modules-wrapper').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'accommodations/accomm_modules', locals: {properties: @accommodations, slider_min: @price_low, slider_max: @price_high})%>")
window.init_isotope()

//Removing the loading icon
$('.refresh-loading').hide()

//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
//Removing this line fixes the issue
marker_string = '<script>window.accommodation_markers = <%= raw @accommodations.to_json %>;</script>'
```

The output of `raw @accommodations.to_json` is the following:

```
[{
    "id": 741580,
    "name": "Gamer's Paradise in Brooklyn!",
    "google_place_id": "ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g",
    "type_code": "hotel",
    "external_id": 2243038,
    "lat": 40.694426,
    "lng": -73.94636,
    "location_rating": 9.0,
    "overall_rating": 9.0,
    "review_count": 13,
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "average_nightly_price": 30.0,
    "image_url": "https://a2.muscache.com/im/pictures/asdfa-4cf7-4222-9204-619200def457.jpg?aki_policy=small",
    "url": "https://www.test.com/rooms/13396285",
    "review_url": "https://www.test.com/rooms/13396285#reviews",
    "accommodation_cluster_id": null,
    "created_at": "2016-12-07T11:22:21.319-08:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-14T08:48:51.073-08:00",
    "usd_average_nightly_price": "30.0",
    "city_rank": 0,
    "city_rank_price": 15,
    "city_rank_reviews": 511,
    "cluster_rank": 0,
    "cluster_rank_price": 0,
    "cluster_rank_reviews": 1,
    "shared_room": true,
    "private_room": false,
    "entire_home": false,
    "external_uid": null
}]
```

This output is valid according to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). How do I go about further debugging and solving this issue?

Comment: @PaulRoub seems correct on this one. Although you should be probably converting to json before assigning it to the instance variable and validating there if you still have issues.

Comment: @Jeff - If I do the conversion (i.e. 'raw') in the controller method instead, I still have the same issue.

Comment: how did you validate it in the controller action? Is the hash you copied an instance when it did not work?

Comment: I assigned an instance variable and ran raw in the controller. `@test = raw @accommodations.to_json`. Then in show.js.coffee, I have `<script>window.accommodation_markers = <%= @test %>;</script>`.  The hash I copied is the exact text when it did not work.

Comment: The `"name": "Gamer's Paradise in Brooklyn!"` part is suspicious given the single quotes around `marker_string`'s value.

Comment: @muistooshort - That was the issue. Want to answer the SO question so I can mark it as correct. Bonus points if you tell me how to escape the single quotes as well :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simplified example and see what happens. If you have this in Ruby:

```
@thing = { :id => 741580, :name => "Gamer's Paradise in Brooklyn!" }
```

and then in some ERB you say:

```
thing = '<%=raw @thing.to_json %>'
```

then you'll see this as the output:

```
thing = '{"id":741580,"name":"Gamer's Paradise in Brooklyn!"}'
```

and there's your problem: neither `raw` nor `<%= ... %>` will quote/escape/encode the `'`. That `raw` call simply tells the ERB engine not to HTML-encode its argument and you're not targeting HTML so you the `raw` functionality in the mix. But you want more, you want those quotes escaped.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to use `String#html_safe` and `escape_javascript`. But you have JavaScript inside a JavaScript string being generated by ERB so you need to double escape things; something unpleasant like:

```
marker_string = '<script>window.accommodation_markers = <%= escape_javascript(escape_javascript(@accommodations.to_json.html_safe)) %>;</script>'
```

I'd strongly lean towards refactoring things so that the "`<script>` inside a JavaScript string" hackery wasn't needed. Three layers of encoding/escaping is a bit much and very error prone.